# Cron Job - Python matplotlib script

Tags: python, matplotlib, cron

I'm new to the whole website world, so I apologize before hand if this is a duplicate question of some kind.

> Important note: I am well aware this specific script won't update the graph. It's just a representation of the script's file path and the output that I want. The graph **will update** when my script is in place and the cron job is run properly.

I have a script that I'm running, say this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.title('Sine Wave')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("home/bdmweath/public_html/images/script_output/test.png")
```

I'm having the script run once an hour, and I have the email set up and it's sending emails. The email I'm getting is:

`/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: /usr/local/bin: is a directory`

The cron job I'm running is:

`/usr/local/bin -q home/bdmweath/public_html/scripts/my_script.py`

HTML code:

```
<div class = 'class_name'>
     <h2>Header Text</h2>
     <a href = 'images/script_output/test.png'><img src='images/script_output/test.png' style="width:20%;height:20%;"></a>
</div>
```

Can anyone explain what is going on why it won't update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run your script using a directory "/usr/local/bin". Presumably you either want to run the script using python:

```
python -q /home/bdmweath/public_html/scripts/my_script.py
```

Or make the script executable and run it directly:

```
chmod +x my_script.py
...
/home/bdmweath/public_html/scripts/my_script.py
```

Comment: I got it to run. I have to do python -x /directory/to/file. Now I'm runninng into an error saying "no module named matplotlib.

Comment: Do you have matplotlib installed in a virtualenv? You might also have it installed globally, but say for python 2 instead of 3 or vice versa?